# DispatchQueue.asyncAfter doesn't work the way I thought it would?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I'm working on an application where the 403 forbidden error I tried to debug was actually caused by an upper bound on the amount of requests you can make to an endpoint per minute (silly me).

All good, I decided to throw my network requests onto a DispatchQueue (better concurrent design anyway) and use the asyncAfter(deadline:execute:) function to cause a 4 second delay between each request.

The design of my program is that each item in a list calls a function, and within that function some work (the request) is put onto that dispatch queue. See below:

```
class ViewController

let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "networkRequests")

func myFirstFunc {
    for item in items {
        self.mySecondFunc(item: item, completionHandler: {(completionItem) in
            // you shouldn't need this
       })
    }
}

func mySecondFunc(item: someType, completionHandler: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            // stuff 
            completionHandler(changedItem)
        })
        self.serialQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4.0) {
                task.resume()
                print(Date())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The way I thought this would work is regardless of if the function is called by different threads concurrently, the code enclosed in the asyncAfter(deadline:execute:) call would be queued up, and the next closure wouldn't start executing until the last closure had completed and an 4 additional seconds had passed.

This didn't work -- print(Date()) has no delays between the printed times.

I fixed it by using the sleep() function in unix, but I'm curious about how this would work in Swift using GCD.

Thanks!

Edit: Specifically looking for the right way to have functionality where a single thread executes each request such that the thread is blocked until the previous is finished with a 4 second delay in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers listed here are effective, but they aren't quite as robust as they could be. Calling `task.resume()` at fixed time intervals does not guarantee that requests are actually sent at those intervals. You are at the mercy of the internal queue maintained by `URLSession.shared`. Adding tasks at 4 second intervals does not mean they will necessarily be sent in that time. It also makes no guarantees about how long a request will take (think mobile networks with poor service). As for `Data(contentsOf:)`, it provides absolutely no real features or customization, such as error handling.

A more robust solution would be to use a `DispatchGroup` and to only initiate a new request 4 seconds after the previous one has completed.

```
class ViewController

let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "networkRequests")
let networkGroup = DispatchGroup()

func myFirstFunc {
    for item in items {
        self.mySecondFunc(item: item, completionHandler: {(completionItem) in
            // you shouldn't need this
       })
    }
}

func mySecondFunc(item: someType, completionHandler: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            // stuff 
            completionHandler(changedItem)

            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 4) // Wait for 4 seconds
            networkGroup.leave() // Then leave this block so the next one can run
        })
        self.networkGroup.notify(queue: serialQueue) {
            networkGroup.wait() // Wait for the previous block to finish
            networkGroup.enter() // Enter a new block
            task.resume()
            print(Date())
        }
    }
}
```

This will guarantee that each subsequent request is sent no sooner than 4 seconds after the previous one finishes, and does not rely on outside factors (like `URLSession`'s internal queue or network stability) to maintain proper timing, without sacrificing the modern features of `URLSession`s.

Comment: Very helpful answer, @Garrett. The one part that bothers me is the call to `Thread.sleep`, which blocks the current thread. I suggest `DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(wallDeadline: DispatchWallTime.now() + 4.0) {
    self.group.leave()
}` instead.

Comment: Good point that there's no guarantee that issuing network calls in a certain order means they will actually execute in that order. Rather than just answering the question asked, you addressed the root issue of the question. (Voted.)

Answer (score 2):

Think about what your code does. It runs through a loop that takes every item in an array and does a call to `asyncAfter()` for each item. The for loop takes almost zero time to execute, so each item gets the same "run 4 seconds from now" delay. (Ok, the last one in a long list might have a delay that's a microsecond later than the first one.)

If you want each request to run 4 seconds after the previous one starts, you need to increase your delay between requests:

```
class ViewController

let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "networkRequests")

func myFirstFunc {
    for (index, item) in items.enumerated {
        self.mySecondFunc(item: item, 
          index: index, 
          completionHandler: {(completionItem) in
            // you shouldn't need this
       })
    }
}

func mySecondFunc(
  item: someType, 
  index: Int,
  completionHandler: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            // stuff 
            completionHandler(changedItem)
        })
        self.serialQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4.0 * index) {
                task.resume()
                print(Date())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you should really refactor your code to not fire off the next request until the previous task completes, and also keep track of the time when you issue each request, calculate how many requests you've issued in the last minute, and once you reach the threshold, wait to issue the next request until the total number of requests issued in the last minute drops below the maximum as the oldest requests "age off".

### EDIT:

After re-reading your question and your comments I have a better idea of what you were trying to do. You're trying to take advantage of the fact that the `DispatchQueue(label:)` intializer gives you a serial queue by default.

The problem is that URLSession is an async framework. When you start a download task, it return immediately. Thus your serial queue of tasks all complete very quickly, but the download tasks stack up in the URLSession and get run according to it's schedule.

If you want to use your serial queue to do downloads, you can use the synchronous `Data(contentsOf:)` initializer to read the data synchronously:

```
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "networkRequests")

func readDataItems {
    for item in items {
        serialQueue.async {
          let data = Data(contentsOf: item.url)
          //Process this data item
          sleep(4)
        }
    }
}
```

Because the `Data(contentsOf:)` function is synchronous, it will cause that task in your serial queue to block until it's finished. Then you sleep the task for 4 seconds before moving on to the next task.

As noted in the first part of my answer, you should really keep track of the time when each task finishes, and only start a download if you haven't exceed the allowed number of downloads/minute.

You could also accomplish the above using an `OperationQueue`, with more flexibility and control.

Comment: This is still terribly flawed. The delay really needs to be 4 seconds after the previous request actually finishes. This answer simply ensures each request is started 4 seconds after the previous is started. Due to network issues, this can still result in all of the requests happening concurrently.

Comment: Yup, I said that in my answer. This answers the OPs question, but is still not a full solution to the problem.

Comment: @rmaddy, if you're feeling ambitious you should implement a proper solution and post it as a better answer. That was more work than I had time for.

Comment: @Duncan C thanks for the explanation. That makes a lot of sense. I thought the way asyncAfter worked is it would put the closure on the queue, and if it is a serial queue not execute the next one until the last one had finished and 4 additional seconds had passed. How would you design it so that each task.resume() is called on the same thread + waits until the previous call is complete, then an additional 4 seconds, then makes the call?

It seems to me I'm looking for something like syncAfter so the thread will block. I'm not sure how to achieve that desired functionality though.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `task.resume()` execute asynchronously so `mySecondFunc` exits and you begin the processing the next request milliseconds later. These requests end up being sent very close together, after an initial 4 second delay for the first one.

To solve this, add a delay parameter to your second function:

```
func myFirstFunc {
    for (index, item) in items.enumerated() {
        self.mySecondFunc(item: item, delay: index * 4) {completionItem in
            // do stuffs
        }
    }
}

func mySecondFunc(item: SomeType, delay: TimeInterval = 0, completionHandler: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
        // stuff
        completionHandler(changedItem)
    }
    self.serialQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
        task.resume()
        print(Date())
    }
}
```

Comment: This is still terribly flawed. The delay really needs to be 4 seconds after the previous request actually finishes. This answer simply ensures each request is started 4 seconds after the previous is started. Due to network issues, this can still result in all of the requests happening concurrently.

Comment: @rmaddy I agree that the requirements are open to intepretation: "cause a 4 second delay between each request". I read that as starting each request 4 seconds apart, not starting next request 4 seconds after the previous one has finished.